# Falla en la importación de 200,000 registros de Excel con PHP hacia SQL Server error 500

Tags: sql-server, ajax, php7

necesito de su ayuda. Requiero de importar 200,000 registros con 33 columnas de excel con php y ajax hacia la base de datos SQL Server, sin embargo; al realizar la importación y revisar la consola y el network me envía error 500, ya amplié el memory_limit = 1024M, max_execution_time = 30000, max_input_time = -1, post_max_size = 800M, upload_max_filesize = 3000M. Al llegar a 17,000 registros simplemente se truncan y me envía el error 500. He revisado en diferentes preguntas del foro y he hecho varias de las sugerencias que postearon, pero aún así no logro solucionar la importación.
A continuación mi código:

```js
function uploadingAm4(){
    let inputAm4CoCo = document.getElementById('dataListAM4co').value;
    let listAm4Period = document.getElementById('dataListAM4period').value;
    let inputAm4Year = document.getElementById('am4Year').value;
    var excelAM4 = $("#importAM4id").val();

    if((inputAm4CoCo == "") || (listAm4Period == "") || (inputAm4Year == "")){
        inputAm4CoCo = "";
        listAm4Period = "";
        inputAm4Year = "";
        return swalfire();
    }
    if (excelAM4 === "") {
        return Swal.fire("Warning","The file is not .xlsx extension","warning");
    }
    var formDataAM4 = new FormData();
    var files =  $("#importAM4id")[0].files[0];
    formDataAM4.append('archivoexcelAM4', files);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'model/importAm4.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formDataAM4,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        /* beforeSend: function(){
            $('#uploadAm4').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#uploadAm4').val('Importing');
            $('#importAM4id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }, */
        success: function(res){
            $('#mostrarTablaAm4').html(res);
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="filesAM4">
    <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <label for="importAM4" class="form-label">Select your Actuals M4 Excel file</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="importAM4id" name="importAM4" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="uploadAm4" name="uploadAm4" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return uploadingAm4()">Upload</button>
            <div class="col-md-12 contentTableModal" id="mostrarTablaAm4"></div>
          </div>
</form>
```

```
     session_start();
     /* variables*/
    $user = $_SESSION['signin'];
    require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    $conn = Conexion::conectardb();

try {
if(is_array($_FILES['archivoexcelAM4']) && count($_FILES['archivoexcelAM4'])>0){

    $max_filesize = 41943040;
    $fileName = $_FILES['archivoexcelAM4']['tmp_name'];
    $readExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileName);
    $excelObj = $readExcel->load($fileName);
    $sheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $row = $sheet->getHighestRow();

    /* echo '<table id="tempBud" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
            <tbody id="tempTbodyAm4">
                <tr>'; */
    $laTablaAm4 ="EXEC Get_Temporary_Importing_Actuals_AM4";
    $byTablaAm4 = $conn->query($laTablaAm4);
        for ($fila=2; $fila <= $row; $fila++) {
                                
            $IdEmpleado = $sheet->getCell('A'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Nombre = $sheet->getCell('B'.$fila)->getValue();
            $RegistroPatronal = $sheet->getCell('C'.$fila)->getValue();
            $CentrodeTrabajo = $sheet->getCell('D'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Concepto = $sheet->getCell('E'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Descripción = $sheet->getCell('F'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Importe = $sheet->getCell('G'.$fila)->getValue();
            $FechadePago = $sheet->getCell('H'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Anio = $sheet->getCell('I'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Mes = $sheet->getCell('J'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Agrupador_Totalizador  = $sheet->getCell('K'.$fila)->getValue();
            $Convenio = $sheet->getCell('L'.$fila)->getValue();
            $TipoSalario = $sheet->getCell('M'.$fila)->getValue();

            $elQueryAm4 = ("INSERT INTO ty_temporary_importing_actuals_am4([Id Empleado],[Nombre],[Registro Patronal],[Centro de Trabajo],[Concepto],[Descripción],[Importe],[Fecha de_ Pago] ,[Año],[Mes],[Agrupador/_Totalizador],[Convenio],[Tipo Salario]) VALUES ('".$IdEmpleado."','".$Nombre."','".$RegistroPatronal."','".$CentrodeTrabajo."','".$Concepto."','".$Descripción."', '".$Importe."','".$FechadePago."','".$Anio."','".$Mes."','".$Agrupador_Totalizador."','".$Convenio."','".$TipoSalario."')");

                $byQueryAm4 = $conn->query($elQueryAm4);
        }
        
}
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
//throw $th;
}
```

Comment: Hacer un insert por registro es caro. Prueba haciendo un insert con múltiples tuplas, con eso tienes menos transacciones y se demora menos. Ya si te quieres divertir más, revisa si puedes hacer bulk insert en tu bd sql server. Y revisa los logs de PHP y trae los errores que salgan allá, con eso las sugerencias van a estar mejor orientadas a tu _verdadero_ problema

Comment: Tendrás algún ejemplo o web que me puedas sugerir para investigar cómo hacerlo¡?